# Using the new CLVisit in CoreLocation

Tags: swift, core-location, ios8

I didn't find anything talking about CLVisit, so I'm trying to explore the technology by myself.

Does anyone know why it isn't working?
All the .plist keys are set and working.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var manager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.startMonitoringVisits()


}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didVisit visit: CLVisit!)
{
    println("visit: \(visit.coordinate.latitude),\(visit.coordinate.longitude)")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you're trying to get these delegate calls while the application is in the background; however, you're instantiating CLLocationManager in the view controller which won't be instantiated (afaik).

This works for me (I am using iOS 8, beta 2, on an iPad mini 2nd gen): Set the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key, enable the "Location updates" background mode in Capabilities, and include the following in `AppDelegate`:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringVisits()

    return true
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didVisit visit: CLVisit!) {
    println("Visit: \(visit)")
    // I find that sending this to a UILocalNotification is handy for debugging
}
```

Update: I have pushed an example application which works to https://github.com/mloughran/CLVisit-POC.

Comment: Worked for me on the device. I don't know how one would go about testing this in the simulator tbh.

Comment: ok, can't get CLLocationManager to work for me on a Beta 2 device. Tried all suggestions. Consider yourself lucky ;-)

Comment: I've added a demo app - maybe see if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks, that worked and then I noticed that I was using the wrong plist in my project. Ugh. But good news it works now for me too. Thx

Comment: I downloaded your Git but id doesn't work. "import CoreLocation" isn't importing CoreLocation and I'm getting "undeclared type CLLocationManager", for example. I already tried to import CoreLocation on "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", but nothing happens...

Comment: It would be nice if apple gave us a way to simulate CLVisits so we can test this without driving around town. Anybody have ideas on simulating these visits?

Comment: I was thinking about using a GPX file.. but don't know how the hardware will pick the visit. Any specific amount of time is needed for a visit to be qualified as CLVisit? @mloughran please throw some light on this. When u tested the github project, for how much time did you stop at a particular location? Also does this work when the app is killed??

Answer (score 7):

Your code looks correct.  I've also found that CLVisit is not working the way I understood it should.  It's tricky to debug, because you have to actually leave your workspace to test it.  :)

The heuristics CLVisit uses to determine a "visit" are undocumented, but according to the WWDC video, you have to stay some unspecified amount of time before CLVisit decides you are visiting and not just passing by. I have had very limited success getting the delegate callback.  Once the arrivalDate visit fired after about two minutes at a location, another after about ten minutes, but most times no visit ever fires.

NSLog doesn't work to catch CLVisits if you are out and about, so I set up a simple Core Data entity and I log all visits:

```
    Visits *thisVisit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Visits" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    thisVisit.arrivalDate = visit.arrivalDate;
    thisVisit.departureDate = visit.departureDate;
    thisVisit.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:visit.coordinate.latitude];
    thisVisit.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:visit.coordinate.longitude];
    [self saveContext];
```

Even when my device has been in my home location for many hours, I don't consistently get either an arrival or a departure event when I leave or return.

EDIT: Here's a complete sample. Install and use it for a few days and you'll see the issues with this new API.  I hope it works better in later betas. 
It's still pretty inconsistent for me - two arrivals in a row sometimes, two departures in a row sometimes, long delays before visit fires...

https://github.com/steveschauer/TestCLVisit

Comment: So ClVisit is pretty buggy and we should wait for a third beta... I stayed in two places for more than 1 hour and nothing was marked(I used NSUserdefaults to store the visits.

Comment: I'm using beta 2 and am getting notifications reliably. In my (limited) experience, departure notifications are more forthcoming, so one is often notified of visits only on leaving a particular location.

Answer (score 1):

I'm beginning to think there is a server component to this API.  My test app does set up in AppDelegate, and with no code changes it has started to intermittently fire off visits just within the last few days. But it misses some and seems to create others.

Here are the last two visits my app recorded.  These points are essentially the same (about 30 feet apart).  I think the first arrival is accurate, but the departure is not.  The second visit's arrival absolutely did not occur. My test device did not leave home during that time.

latitude: xx.11852879438132
longitude: -xxx.7792256808099
arrivalDate: 2014-06-25 12:19 PM
departureDate: 2014-06-25 4:44 PM

latitude: xx.1185726857039
longitude: -xxx.7793685278068
arrivalDate: 2014-06-26 5:59 AM
departureDate: distantFuture

Earlier I took it out and about a bunch of times and got visits to fire only occasionally.